# Find words that are 6 characters in length

Tags: bash, parsing, text-parsing

I have a file.txt

```
fhadja
ksjfskdasd
adasda
sada
s
adasaaa
```

I need to extract only the words that are 6 character length from there.

EXAMPLE of what i need to obtain as a result:

```
fhadja
adasda
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -E '^.{6}$' file
fhadja
adasda
```

Or using awk:

```
awk 'length($0)==6' file
fhadja
adasda
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed -rn '/^.{6}$/p' file
fhadja
adasda
```

Comment: but if I need also all the words that starts with letter "f" and with the length 6? Thank you!

Comment: Then use: `grep -E '^f.{5}$' file`

Answer (score 3):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep -E '^.{6}$' file
```

Output:

```
fhadja
adasda
```

Answer (score 1):

Or perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if 6 == tr/\n//c' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: Another solution in `bash`

```
while read -r line
do
    if [ ${#line} -eq 6 ]
    then
      echo $line
    fi
done < file.txt
```

you get,

```
fhadja
adasda
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file can contain spaces, make sure you're matching non-blank characters:

```
grep -oE '\<[[:graph:]]{6}\>' << END
 fhadja
   ksjfskdasd
   adasda
   sada s 123456
   s
 2 4 6
END
```

```
fhadja
adasda
123456
```